# How to solve program recursively

Tags: java, recursion, prime-factoring

I need help with a program that satisfies the following quote:

> All integers >= 2 can be factored into the product of only prime
>   numbers.  For instance, the number 12 has a prime factorization of
>   2*2*3, while the number 100 has a prime factorization of 2*2*5*5.  We
>   are interested in knowing whether an input integer has a prime
>   factorization that only has 2s and 3s.

I think I need more base conditions and a catch all recursive call.

Current (unfinished) Code:

```
    public static boolean hasFactors2and3(int number) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        if (number < 2) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number is less than 2");
        if (number >= 2 && number < 5) return true; // because for all these numbers it works
        if (number % 2 == 0) return hasFactors2and3(number /= 2);
        if (number % 3 == 0) return hasFactors2and3(number /= 3);

    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is not a code-writing or homework-finishing service.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively

Comment: This doesn't return a value in every case. What value should it return if the number passes all the `if` statements? Can you think of a number that would?

Comment: At the expense of some speed, I would suggest factoring the number into a `List` of the factors, and then check to see if the `List` had anything other than a 2 or a 3. The advantage, IMHO, is a slightly better ability to error check as well as a bit better future proofing (i.e., easy to add a new test on the factors to see if there is a 5). In other words, be a bit more general in the factorization and apply the test logic separately.

Comment: Don't use recursion unless your assignment specifically called for it.  There isn't anything necessarily recursive about this problem.

Comment: Recursion is about solving a problem by solving a smaller version of the same problem.  In this case, a smaller version of the problem would be on `number/2` or `number/3`.  That's the biggest hint I think you should get.

Comment: The code you have looks sound, but as you say, incomplete. When you reach the bottom of it, you know that `number` is at least 5 and that neither 2 nor 3 divide into it. Can you figure out how to handle such a number?

Comment: @ajb isn't that already in the posted code?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger looks like I didn't notice it because he used the wrong operator (`/=`, which works but serves no purpose, and is uncommon enough that my eyes just missed it...)

Comment: @ajb that's true... I missed it the other way, haven't *seen* the assignment part of the operator.

Answer (score 1):

You ask for a recursive solution.  I won't give you that.  Instead I will give you a non-recursive solution in pseudocode and leave it up to you to convert it into a recursive solution.

```
function hasFactors2and3(number)

  // Deal with negatives, 0, 1.
  if (number < 2)
    return false
  endif

  // Remove factors of 2.
  while (number MOD 2 == 0)
    number <- number / 2
  endwhile

  // Remove factors of 3.
  while (number MOD 3 == 0)
    number <- number / 3
  endwhile

  // See what factors are left after removing all 2s and 3s.
  return number == 1

end function
```

Hint: research how to remove tail recursion by using a loop and then reverse the process.